# Limit choices to

Tags: python, django-models

I have a model named Project which has a m2m field users. I have a task model with a FK project. And it has a field assigned_to. How can i limit the choices of assigned_to to only the users of the current project?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this another way, using this nifty form factory trick.

```
def make_task_form(project):
    class _TaskForm(forms.Form):
        assigned_to = forms.ModelChoiceField(
              queryset=User.objects.filter(user__project=project))

        class Meta:
            model = Task
    return _TaskForm
```

Then from your view code you can do something like this:

```
project = Project.objects.get(id=234)
form_class = make_task_form(project)
...
form = form_class(request.POST)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a [custom form for the admin](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin).

Your form should contain a [ModelChoiceField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField) in which you can specify a queryset parameter that defines what the available choices are.  This form *can* be a ModelForm.

*(the following example assumes users have an FK to your Project model)*

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    assigned_to = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Users.objects.filter(user__project=project))

    class Meta:
        model = Task
```

Then assign the form to the ModelAdmin.

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import Task
from forms import TaskForm

class TaskAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = TaskForm
admin.site.register(Task, TaskAdmin)
```

Comment: My users don't have a FK to my project model. But my Project model has a M2M field users.

Comment: The idea is the right one, but the code as given will not work, as the 'project' variable is undefined. The right-hand side of a queryset parameter must be an actual value or variable, not a field on the model. You actually need to override the form's `__init__` method here to get this to work.